# chrome_path "module" object not callable

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to inspect a webpage and get the information but at a line it shows that "module" not callable
and my code is:

[image]

Please help me with this. Thank you

Comment: I would suggest to use Notepad / IDE rather than CLI

Answer (score 3):

You are using wrong module name. Use

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chrome_exe_path/chromedriver.exe")
```

instead of `webdriver.chrome`

Comment: this is a great catch!

Comment: @Yagav, Please accept the answer if its helpful for you So it can be helpful for others as well. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is a spelling mistake in the syntax! The third line should be `webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)` instead of `webdriver.chrome(chrome_path)`.